# How to save ArrayField as set in Django

Tags: django, django-models

The goal is removing of duplicates from list field while saving model. For example creation in migration:

```
def migrate_model(apps, *args):
    MyModel = apps.get_model('my_app.MyModel')
    m = MyModel.objects.create(
        array_field=['123','123'],
    )
    m.array_field  # ['123']
```

I tried to overwrite `save` but it doesn't work

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    array_field = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=5))
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.array_field:
            self.array_field = list(set(self.array_field))
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Just removing duplicates then saving?

Comment: @AdamJaamour yes, but I want to have a single place for this logic. I don't want to use `list(set(` everywhere.

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work. How do you save the objects? Did you try to debug? Just add print command in the `save` method and see what happens.

Comment: @cezar I created object in migration. Maybe it matters. I edited question

Comment: Do you call that method in the migrations file like `operations = [migrations.RunPython(migrate_model)]`?

Comment: @cezar exactly. I use  it in `operations`

Comment: @DanielM did you ever get to solve your problem? Was my answer below useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Careful, the `save()` method is **NOT** called when using [`create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects) according to django docs.

Maybe that is causing you the problems, because your overriden save method doesn't actually gets called.

Comment: Did this help you? Could you get it working? If so, I would appreciate if you marked the answer as accepted.